# C++ logging framework for iOS and Android NDK

Tags: iphone, c++, logging, android-ndk

I'm looking for a C++ logging framework for iOS and Android NDK with these features:

- Supports iOS and Android NDK
- Logs have a severity (info, warning, error, critical, etc)
- Control over which logging statements are enabled or disabled
- Manage output destinations

I looked at the frameworks suggested in other posts asking about c++ logging frameworks but the iOS and Android NDK requirement does not seem to be met.

Comment: Maybe take it as a hint, and take the logging framework you like the most and make a backend for iOS and Android for it? Itches to scratch and all that. :)

Comment: ".. does not seem to be met." Have you actually tried? It would be surprising is e.g. Google-glog would not work on Android NDK.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [zf_log](https://github.com/wonder-mice/zf_log) logging library. It could be too simple for your purposes, but it supports both Android and iOS and satisfies your other requirements. Not sure what you meant by "Manage output destinations" though, but it supports custom output functions.